# Accessing the element a directive is bound to

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive that is applied to elements to set their max height equal to the window height minus the distance from the top of the element to the top of the window.

I was trying it like this

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
return function (scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);
    scope.getWindowDimensions = function() {
        return { 'h': w.height() };
    };
    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        //get header height including margins
        var headerHeight = $('.page-header').outerHeight(true);

        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;

        scope.style = function() {
            return {
                'height': (scope.windowHeight  - headerHeight) + 'px',
                'max-height': (scope.windowHeight  - headerHeight) + 'px'
            };
        };
    }, true);

    w.bind('resize', function() {
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
})
```

But I would have to add a var for every element that is above the element whose height I want to set.  So I believe using

```
var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#my-element').offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
```

would be better as it does all the measurements relative to the element its setting but how do I access this element from within the directive without adding any extra classes or identifiers?

Also do I need to create an isolate scope for me to use this more than once on a single page?

My goal is to basically have my web apps body element equal to the height of the window and any containing divs that are higher than that height to have scroll bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1)It would be better if you have isolate scope. so that the directive can be user multiple elements with different heights.
 2) Send an array of elements (Which are above the required element) as an attribute to the directive. And calculate the height to be deducted from window height.
```

Comment: Thanks why do you think it is better to send an array of elements into the directive than just measure from the top of the element?

Comment: I thought if 2 elements one after another use the same directive, then it will work fine.